# TFS 2010 - WebDeploy to IIS6

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

I have setup a build configuration in TFS2010 with MSBuild arguments to deploy using WebDeploy to a remote IIS6 webserver.  I can deploy to this remote web server using WebDeploy manually from VS2010 without issue.  But, when I kick off the TFS build it fails with a permission denied error when attempting to deploy to the remote box.  I have added the user to the Administrator group on the webserver box.

I found in the security event log that the Domain wasn't set:

Logon Failure:
Reason:                  Unknown user name or bad password
User Name:            tfssvcUser
Domain:
Logon Type:            3
Logon Process:      NtLmSsp
Authentication Package:        NTLM 
Workstation Name: TFSServer

When I run it manually the Domain is set.  tfssvcUser is a domain user is running as such on the build server.

I am running MSDeploy 1 right now.

Any ideas?

Comment: assuming both the web server and the build server are in the same domain? (I only see you mentioned the build srv)

Comment: Yes they are in the same domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the admin for the TFS box had misread the permissions on the build server and needed to add permissions to a temp folder or registry, not sure which.